Sludge Production in a Wastewater Treatment Plant
One of the challenges I frequently face in the operation and maintenance of wastewater treatment plants is accurately determining sludge production. Generally, I am required to submit a report that quantifies and substantiates the amount of sludge generated. However, the data I am typically provided for the plant is minimal, including only influent flow rate (m³/day), COD, BOD₅, and suspended solids concentrations at both the inlet and outlet. With this limited information, I attempt to apply standards such as ATV, but these standards often require additional data, which I unfortunately do not have. I am attaching the equations provided by this model.



where

My search through scientific literature has also yielded little guidance. Are there any theoretical models or equations available that could estimate the total sludge generated—including both pretreatment sludge and sludge from the biological reactor—using only the data provided?

What are the meanings of $\pu{SP_{d,C}, B_{d,BOD}, X_{SS,IAT}}$ ? and all the other parameters of the formula ?

@Maurice You are right. I edit the post to include its meaning.
